# Is it possible to make large title in navigation bar clickable (iOS)

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

For a regular title, I could set titleView to customize the title fully. But for the large title, I did not see any possibility to customize it except modifying core kit. Does anyone figure out how to make that clickable?

Also, is it possible to show either title or large title but not both? It looks like that after a title view set, that title view shows forever.

Comment: You already know the answers to both questions so this is really just a complaint. It would be better to file an enhancement request with Apple.

Comment: @matt, not a complaint. Just wanna make sure and see if we have any hack way to do it before sending a request to big fruit.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah you can modify title size in navigation bar for that you can do following things

1- first go to navigation controller which is attach to your view controller 
2- After that you can select navigation bar of navigation controller 
3- When you select navigation Bar then go to inspector panel .In inspector panel there is a option "Title Text Attributes".In this You can select "Title font" option inside this You can increase and decrease the size of title

There is also a lot of option for Editing title of navigation bar i.e.
- Title Color
- Title Shadow
- Title font

Comment: Not answer my questions. Actually, to make title clickable, I use a customized button, format UI and add action to it. But it shows forever even if large title displayed. Anyway to prevent both of them showing on the screen?